# Decreasing byte size of integer block in socket communication

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, algorithm, sockets

I am developing a multiplayer game server.

On my case, every single byte that really matter for gaming experience and saving bandwith.

Client and server will send some integer values each other. 
Integers mostly will have values lower than 100. 
In some cases, that integers could have  values between 0 and 100000.

All that integers will be send in same sequence. (Imagine that they are integer array)

Using 8 bit integer array or 16 bit integer array is not an option to me because of possible values greater than 65535.
And, I do not want to use 32 bit integer array just for the values what be in action rarely.

So, I developed an algorithm for that (here is the javascript port):

```js
function write(buffer, number){
    while(number > 0x7f){
        buffer.push(0x80 | (number & 0x7f));
        number >>= 7;
    }
    buffer.push(number);
}

function read(buffer){
    var cur, result = 0, shift = 0x8DC54E1C0; // ((((((28 << 6) | 21) << 6) | 14) << 6) | 7) << 6;
    while((cur = buffer.shift()) > 0x7f)
    {
        result |= (cur & 0x7f) << shift;
        shift >>= 6;
    }
    return result | (cur << shift);
}

var d = [];
var number = 127;
write(d, number);

alert("value bytes: " + d);


var newResult = read(d);


alert("equals : " + (number === newResult));
```

My question is: Is there a better way to solve that problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use a reserved control code to indicate to the unpacker to take two chunks instead of one. if most of the values are under 100, it's probably most efficient to use hex or base36 number shipped as text, CSV for example. that would consume 3bytes per number on small numbers, and a few more on larger ones...

Comment: @dandavis - For values less than 100, his proposed solution consumes exactly one byte. It seems to me like a good solution.

Comment: What is your communication protocol - TCP or UDP?

Comment: Why not just compress the packets?

Comment: I'd say, easier would be to prefix your stream with a bit-mask style size of next N fields. You can pack size of 4 fields into one byte, which is not that bad. However, I honestly doubt 4 bytes in every integer will make a difference.

Comment: @keithmo: curious, how does it use one byte? when `d` is alerted, i see 127, which needs 3 (str) or 4 bytes (number) to ship, what am i missing?

Comment: @dandavis: Based on the masking and shifting I assume `buffer` is simulating an array of bytes with each element `>= 0` and `<= 255`. If so, and `write` is called with `number <= 127`, then the while loop is not executed at all, so just a single byte is pushed to the array.